# seeding not getting data back

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am trying to seed, save in users then get the userId and insert into account table:

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.join(
    // Deletes ALL existing entries
    knex('users').del(), 
    knex('accounts').del(),

    // Inserts seed entries
    knex('users').insert({
        uerId: '1231231',
        email: 'kel@test.com'
    }).then(function(result){
      knex('accounts').insert({
        accountId: '0',
        userId: result[0].userId
      });
    })
  );
};
```

But the problem is the result getting is the inserted rows value? How can I get back the data?

Comment: Is it also a typo you are specifying uerId not userId?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo here: `accountId: ''0',` remove double '' before the zero

Comment: It is a typo when posting the question.